# Google search console collects data for two websites within the same property even though there is separate properties for both

Tags: google-search-console

we have two websites, the first one is the main website e.g `example.com` while the other website looks like a directory within the main domain eg. `example.com/xyz`, but it has been hosted on a different server than the main website.

But our Google search console collects data for both websites within the same property, although we have separate properties for the two. Why?

Comment: Directories cannot usually be hosted by a separate server unless you use a reverse proxy.  Is that the case here?

Comment: The only way for Google to treat them differently, is to set it up on a separate subdomain. So you can have one at example.com and the other one at www.example.com

Comment: Hi Stephen, it's a sub folder, not a reverse proxy.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, Luis. I am writing a proposal for my management to move our subdirectories to a different domain because of these issues, can you suggest something?